# Zend 2 variable from controller to layout.html

Tags: php, variables, layout, zend-framework2

I am new Zend 2. I succeed to pass data to my viewmodel, but now I want to pass a var to my layout.phtml

How can i do that?

controller:

```
<?php

namespace Pages\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    function indexAction() {
        $this->layout()->myVariable = array('bas'=>'man');
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'data' => 'home'
        ));      
}
```

}

layout.phtml:

```
print_r($this->layout()->myVariable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this within your Controller

```
$this->layout()->setVariable('myVariable', 'Value');
```

Or just do :

```
$this->layout()->myVariable = 'Value';
```

Comment: You have to add it within your action

Comment: Use $this->layout()->myVariable to display it.

Comment: new Viewmodel and $this->layout doesnt work together. If i only use $this->layout then it works. Is it possible to append it?

Comment: It’s just because you return before assigning. Switch the assignment before the Viewmodel.